# Name of generalised inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, determinant, inner-products

The inner product of a complex vector space acts as $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle: V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$, and has a geometric interpretation as returning the angle between two vectors
$$
\theta(a,b) = \arccos \left( \sqrt{\frac{\langle a,b \rangle\langle b,a \rangle}{\langle a,a \rangle \langle b,b \rangle}} \right)
$$

Is there a name for, geometric interpretation of, and literature surrounding the following object that takes two sets of $n$ vectors and returns the determinant of the matrix of inner products $G: V^n \times V^n \to \mathbb{C}$
$$
G(\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\},\{b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n \} ) = \det\begin{pmatrix}
\langle a_1 , b_1 \rangle & \langle a_1 , b_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle a_1 , b_n \rangle 
\\
\langle a_2 , b_1 \rangle & \langle a_2 , b_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle a_2 , b_n \rangle 
\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots
\\
\langle a_n , b_1 \rangle & \langle a_n , b_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle a_n , b_n \rangle 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I ask as I noticed it seems a similar angle can be defined
$$
\phi(\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\},\{b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n \}) = \arccos \left( \sqrt{\frac{ G(\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\},\{b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n \} ) G(\{b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n\},\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n \} )}{G(\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\},\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n \} ) G(\{b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n\},\{b_1, b_2, \cdots b_n \} )}} \right)
$$
where (I think) $\phi = 0$ if the $a_i$ and $b_j$ have the same span, and $\phi = \pi/2$ if there exists a linear combination of the $a_i$ that is orthogonal to all the $b_j$ (and vice versa).

Comment: You could interpret this determinant as the inner product over the [exterior power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Exterior_power) $\wedge^n V$. Indeed, we have
$$
\langle a_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge a_n, b_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge b_n \rangle = G(\{a_1,\dots,a_n\},\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}).
$$
Your $\phi$ is then the angle between two vectors in $\wedge^n V$.

Comment: It is no restriction to assume that $V = \mathbb C^d$. If $A := [a_1,\ldots,a_n]\in\mathbb C^{d\times n}$ and $B := [b_1,\ldots,b_n]\in\mathbb C^{d\times n}$, then $G(A,B) = \det(B^*A)$. Note that this is always zero when $n>d$, so you should have $n\le d$. There is also the Frobenius inner product, which is defined by $\langle A,B\rangle = tr(B^*A)$, where $tr$ denotes the trace. This one is indeed an inner product.